# How can I segregate user data in firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm creating an app that has uses a firebase Cloud Firestore database.  The structure seems to be collection/document/fields.  I am thinking of either using the user id as the prefix to the collection name or simply a field for userId.

I'm currently using:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Events").
```

This could be changed to prefix event with the userId

I am currently reading everything in using:

```
reference(to: "Events").addSnapshotListener{ (snapshot, _) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}
    for document in snapshot.documents {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Todd put together a [great series on Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) and it covers database architecture in depth in eposides [#3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s) and [#4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo).

Comment: Thanks Kato and Doug Stevenson for the links to more information.  From the console, it was not obvious that I could create a path.  I have done that.  Now from the console, I can't see the paths I have created.  I'll use the linked information to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a really good idea to use prefixes on collection names.  That doesn't work well with security rules.

The usual structure for per-user data is to have a collection with documents whose IDs are the user IDs.  Then, you can further organize other data in subcollections under that document ID.

```
/users
  /uid1
  /uid2
    /events
    /likes
    /history
```

Then, you can [write security rules using the user's UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) very easily.